# load subview over self.view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I am trying to add a UIView over the current view, but having no luck.. I am sure my code is correct but not sure what else to check, what else should I be thikning about when inserting subviews

this is what I have added into viewDidLoad

```
//..
    cellContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];

    cellContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 480.0, 320.0, 300.0);

    [self.view addSubview:cellContainer];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//..
```

cellContainer is declared in the header as a UIView... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try changing color of cellContainer. Else send me code I'll look into this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cellContainer` is likely getting added to the view hierarchy of of the `UIViewController`, but you've set the frame such that it is offscreen.  Try this:

```
 cellContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
 [self.view addSubview:cellContainer];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

This will display `cellContainer` at the top left of the view, extending 320px in the right-x direction, and 300px in the down-y direction.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you very much.. I think I need to go rest.. almost kicked a hole in my computer... thank you very much for the help.